# Mongo is unable to start

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to start mongo uin windows10 by type: `mongo` in cmd.

I am getting this error:

```
C:\Users\Itzik>mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2016-12-26T19:00:16.604+0200 W NETWORK  [main] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2016-12-26T19:00:16.605+0200 E QUERY    [main] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:234:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed

C:\Users\Itzik>
```

I have opened port 27017 in the firewall,
and restart mongo's services 
and it still dont work.

what could it be?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In C:\Program Files\MongoDB\ you might not have permission to create file/folder for your user. And **mongo** installer cannot create it because of lack of Administrative permission for your user.

So in C:\Program Files\MongoDB:

1. Create  a folder named **data**
2. Create a folder named **db** inside the folder **data**
3. Now right click on the data folder and choose **properties**
4. Click **security** tab and select your user there
5. Click the **Full control** select box
6. Click ok, ok, ok ...
7. **important!**   if you don't have the path "**C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin**" set in environment variable, please set it.
8. Now go to shell and type : **mongod --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\data\db"**

That's it :)

Answer (score 35):

Have you started the server? Mongodb follows a server-client architecture. `mongo` is the client, but before it is started you need to start `mongod`, which is the server.

If you haven't, start the server in advance in a different console:

```
mongod --dbpath "c:\data"
```

replacing c:\data by any folder where you want to store your data (you need to create the folder in advance).

If `mongod` is not in the path look in the installation path, it should be something like `C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe`.

When the server says something like 'waiting for connections', then you can go to another console and type `mongo` to start the client.

Answer (score 4):

First start the server.
Goto your installation path. Mine was in "Program Files/Mongodb/server/bin"

You will find a "mongod.exe" application.

However, the server will look for "C:/data" folder for all the databases. 
So create the "C:/data" folder.

Now start the mongod.exe using command prompt.

```
>>mongod
```

After this you may start the client

```
>>mongo
```

This worked out for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Open the terminal as Administrator**.

   (You can simply do this by searching cmd in start and then right click and select "Run as administrator")
2. Go to bin directory of your MongoDB folder.

   **cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin**
3. Type following command to start mongodb server :

   **mongod --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\Data"**

   now, server will be waiting for connections.
4. Open a new command prompt(again as Administrator)
5. Go to bin directory.

   **cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin**
6. Type following command:

   **mongo**

This will show you a prompt of mongodb :

```
  >
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if u install by brew (on osx) 
first run `sudo mkdir /data/db` 
start mondoDB Daemon by typing `mongod` (leave it open) and then  
run mongo by typing `mongo` in new terminal tab

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced the same problem.
First i have typed mongodb in my command prompt ,It displays "**waiting for connection on 27017**" that means it is working.
Then i type mongo in another Command prompt Window then above error occurred.

I was having both *.dll* files in my *xampp\php\ext* folder.
(**php_mongo.dll** and **php_mongodb.dll**)
I deleted **Php_mongodb.dll** and also it's extension from **php.ini** file.

Again restart command prompt,Type mongod and then mongo 
Now working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First set the path in Enviroment Variables, `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin`
after that use  bellow command

- `C:\>mkdir data`
- `C:\>cd data`
- `C:\data>mkdir db`
- `C:\data\db>`

Then go to bin directory and select `mongod.exe` or use `mongod`. Without closing previous cmd
open a new cmd and start the client using `mongo`
Now it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by creating a data directory

Then move to the bin folder of mongodb or setting path information in environment variables

Then you can enter the following command,

mongod --dbpath 'path of the data folder including data directory name'

Eg: mongod --dbpath c:\users\codemaker\data